# Temporal Flux + Blizzard stack slow effects stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Do the effects of temporal flux (the passive skill) and blizzard stack? How much slowed down will the enemies be then?

Answer (score 2):

As with all slows, they don't stack per-ce, but they will both do their expected slows, ie. they won't overwrite each other. If you apply two different slows with different durations the highest slow amount will win out for it's duration. If there is another slow on the creature when it wears off, that slow will take effect. So, for example:

You apply both a 10 second slow for 50% slow and a 5 second slow for 80% at the same time. The creature will be slowed by 80% for 5 seconds, then by 50% for a further 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

That answer is so wrong! they do stack together.

Best way to test it, that angel boss before diablo izual in act 4.If you slow him with just blizzard and then if you slow him with blizzard AND a arcane damage spell with temporal flux rune on ,(desintegrate).
You will obviously notice the difference in how much he is slowed down.It does stack.

Comment: Chilled is 30% slow and temporal flux is 30%.Between a 30% slow and double that.Just try it on izual if you can, you will notice the large difference on the slows.